# find_in_batches Alternatives in Rails 1.1.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I do like `find_in_batches` in Rails 1.1.6?

The application based on Rails 1.1.6 should keep the Rails version and treat numerous records and `Model.find(:all).each do |model| xxx end` must consume numerous memory space and time. The current performance looks very bad. However, to do the same thing more economically is a must issue.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Oh my goodness! Is this for real? 1.1.6?...

Comment: It's a serious issue.

Comment: well, just patch Rails with `find_in_batches` functionality? :)

Comment: An application that hasn't been updated in 10 years has performance issues? ;-)